# Bodybuilder js: Bucket Filter Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, bodybuilder.js

I would like to make buckets based of keyword-occurences in a field.

I checked elasticsearch documentation and found Filters Aggregation should be a good fit:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation

Currently we're using bodybuilder.js to build queries. I found in the source code (https://github.com/danpaz/bodybuilder/blob/master/src/aggregation-builder.js#L87) an undocumented function:

```
bodybuilder()
     .aggregation('terms', 'title', {
         _meta: { color: 'blue' }
         }, 'titles')
        .build()
```

what results in:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "titles": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title"
      },
      "meta": {
        "color": "blue"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But that's actually not the same structure like described in ES documentation:

```
GET logs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "messages" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : [
          { "match" : { "body" : "error"   }},
          { "match" : { "body" : "warning" }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea how to achieve Filters Aggregations with bodybuilder.js ?

Comment: did you find a solution for this, I struggle as well here with bodybuilder.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a solution for **bodybuilder.js** but one for javascript using a library - very similar to bodybuilder.js. Its called **[elastic-builder.js](https://elastic-builder.js.org/)**.

Regarding your question this code:

```
esb.requestBodySearch()
    .agg(esb.filtersAggregation('messages')
    .filter('errors', esb.matchQuery('body', 'error'))
    .filter('warnings', esb.matchQuery('body', 'warning')));
```

will give you this response:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "messages": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "errors": { "match": { "body": "error" }},
          "warnings": { "match": { "body": "warning" }}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like bodybuilder.js is mostly build for queries and its easier to use for such purpose. If you want more control without the heavy json overhead elastic-builder could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it like this in  bodybuilder.js:

```
bodybuilder().aggregation('filters', {
    "filters": {
        "errors": { "term": { "body": "error" } },
        "warnings": { "term": { "body": "warning" } }
    }
}, 'messages').build();
```

above code will generate the query:

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "messages" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : {
          "errors" :   { "term" : { "body" : "error"   }},
          "warnings" : { "term" : { "body" : "warning" }}
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```